# Design thinking of Solicitation node address in IPv6

Tags: ip, ipv6, protocol-theory, multicast, rfc

Recently I study RFC 4291, and the solicitation node address is defined in that spec. I know what and the function of this solicitation node address. But just wondering why does the address design as

```
FF02::1:FFXX:XXXX
```

I mean why choose the 104 bits as fix prefix, and just use 24 bits of the unicast IP address as variation.

I also know that "all nodes on the link" defined as :

```
FF02::1
```

As far as I know the FF02 means multicast on the local link, but beyond that are there any correlation between them ?

Any tips or references are appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I mean why choose the 104 bits as fix prefix, and just use 24 bits of
>   the unicast IP address as variation.

The RFC clearly explains this:

> IPv6 addresses that differ only in the high-order bits (e.g., due to
>   multiple high-order prefixes associated with different aggregations)
>   will map to the same Solicited-Node address, thereby reducing the
>   number of multicast addresses a node must join.

IPv6 allows, and even requires, multiple addresses per interface. Every IPv6 unicast and anycast address that an interface has must have a corresponding solicited node address.

Comment: Yes, I have read this paragraph, but that time somehow I didn't relate it to my question. My question is why not design solicitation node address as FF02:1:XXXX:XXXX [use 32 bits of the unicast address. ] I try to interpret that paragraph again. Does that means that since under an aggregation the nodes' address in the higher order bits are all the same [maybe all the 128 - 32 = 96 bits are same], so we don't need too much solicitation multicast group ?

Comment: Suppose you had these addresses on the interface: `2001:db8:1234::1`, `2001:db8:5678::1`, and `2001:db8:90ab::1`. The solicited-node address would be the same for all, and that would mean only one multicast group to join instead of three. The last 64 bits of the addresses will often be the same because of SLAAC or manual configuration.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Since the last 64 bits will be the same, we just use 24 bits as the variation? Does that design also consider the link-local unicast address?

Comment: Since the last 64 bits will often be the same, the last 24 bits will be, too, and that will save on subscribed multicast groups. The link-local unicast address will often be based on the MAC address, matching the last 64 bits of the SLAAC unicast addresses, or manually configured to match the last 64 bits of the global unicast address(es).

Comment: Hi Ron, I see the last 24 bits of unicast link-local address on my linux computer is the last three bytes of my MAC address. Is this a coincidence to the solicitation node address's variation part[24 bytes] or is intentional?

Comment: That is how SLAAC assigns addresses. It splits the MAC address in half, inserts FFFE in the middle to make the 48-bit MAC address 64 bits, and flips the U/L bit.

Comment: OK, thanks!! I got it. Many thanks for your guidence

Comment: This still doesn't answer why only the last 24 hits are imported into the Solicited Node Multicast address. Why not the last 32, or 48, or even 64 bytes of the unicast address? Each of those would still make a single SNM address from your example.

Comment: The fewer the bits, the more likely they are to match the other addresses. The last 24 bits of a MAC address are a good choice since they are unique for that manufacturer, whereas the first 24 bits of the MAC address and the added FFFE would be the same. That means 24 bits should be just enough to tell the difference between interfaces; more would be unnecessary.